# Define DateTime Formats and Convert One to another Using Momentjs

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have one DateTime value in two different formats:
 1. Sun Jun 28 2015 06:00:00 GMT-0400 
 2. 6/28/2015 6:00 AM

Is there any terms/names commonly used that could uniquely define each one?
And how to convert format 1 to 2 using Momentjs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. You can format it later by checking `moment.js` docs.

```
var moment = require('moment');

var date = new Date('Sun Jun 28 2015 06:00:00 GMT-0400')
var a = moment(date).format('L hh:mm A');

console.log(a);
```